# Unity3d. Cannot allocate memory importing package

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, fatal-error, allocation

When I try to import my project (exported from windows)in my mac, it shows a fatal error that says: cannot allocate memory.

It cannot be my computer since it has 32 gb RAM and the package is only 1.44 gb size.

When I import the project in the pc with windows it imports the project without problems.

Im using the same version of unity in both computers( unity3d 4.6.3).

Im using osx yosemite and I dont know how to specifically assign more ram to a program (if thats the solution).

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to use a single package? Unity 4's editor is 32-bit and may not be able to map an address space large enough to work with a file of that size.

Comment: Hi, yes, i thought that at the beginning. But then why does it run on windows and not in IOS X if I'm using the same version of unity in both?

Comment: Can you break the package into sub-packages? It may sound extremely tedious (and it is) but if the error message doesn't provide any detail, there's hardly anything else you can do to locate the faulty asset (except maybe google for similar errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. If anyone is interested, In my pc (windows) the package was imported without problem then I took the folders from the project in windows explorer and compress then. Then i Decompressed those folders in my mac, and opened the folder where the other folders were via unity and it worked. So far, no bugs for doing that. Ill let you know if any bug appear for doing it that way.